# how to reduce the acquisition speech time in pocketshpinx

Tags: speech-recognition, cmusphinx

As the title , I'm work on a Speech Recognition System with pocketshpinx on embedded device.I have install pocketshpinx on my embedded device.But the acquisition speech time is vrey slow and the recognition results is bad.During the running of the application,the acquisition speech time cost about 5000ns to compute_frame_pow.Is it necessary?How can I improve the compute rate?

Answer (score 0):

There are many algorithms implemented inside pocketsphinx to run at very fast speed. Some are enabled by default, some needs to be turned on. There is actually a wiki page about that:

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/pocketsphinxhandhelds

However, you need to be aware that speed optimization is a complex process. In many cases speed is traded of for accuracy and you need to be very careful about that. Accuracy itself is also an issue. I recommend you the following:

1. Make sure you are using proper acoustic model and you are using the decoder properly. It's very easy to screw down the accuracy with incorrect setup. Any optimization has no sense after that. You could share your setup and tests on forum or diretly with the developers (me) if you need a professional help.
2. Setup a test database to track the current accuracy and speed. Track down the performance along the process.
3. Profile your application to understand which component takes most time
4. Enable algorithms to speedup that component and see how speed improves.

Comment: i had found which component takes most time.But i donnt know how to reduce the time.then i want to know whether the pocksphinx-0.4 can recognition the form of wav file in directly .(i know pocksphinx 0.7 can do this).

Comment: There is no sense to use 0.4. Just use 0.7